# Understanding parsing of data in C++ (For a newer programmer)

Tags: c++, string, parsing, stack

I have data in the format: 
(The data can be input as a string, or from a file, our choice, but i prefer a string)

First_Name Last_Name Number Date Duration

such as:
John Doe 5593711872 09122010 12

I need to parse this data and then place it into a "Contacts" class, one per each entry.

I then need to place 5 of these entries into a stack, and print them out.

I know how to process it, but how do I parse and split this data into the relevant sections?

(edit, adding what little code snippet i've got.  I'm looking more for understanding than code, or is that not how this site works?)

contact.h:

```
 #ifndef contact_h
#define contact_h

#include <iostream> //this is the set of functions we need to "overload" and break out
using std::ostream; //use both output halves
using stf::istream; //and input halves

#include <string>
using std::string;


class Contact
{
      friend ostream &operator<<( ostream &, const Contact & ); //from example 11.3 in powerpoint 3
      friend ostream &operator>>( istream &, Contact & ); //also from example 11.3 in powerpoint 3
private:
        string first;
        string last;
        string number;
        string date;
        int talk_time;
};
```

Phone.h

```
#ifndef phone_h
#define phone_h

#include <iostream> //this is the set of functions we need to "overload" and break out
using std::ostream; //use both output halves
using stf::istream; //and input halves

#include <string>
using std::string;

class Phone
{
      friend ostream &operator<<( ostream &, const Phone & ); 
      friend ostream &operator>>( istream &, Phone & ); 
private:
        string area; //area code segment
        string threes; //then the three-digit section
        string fours; //and lastly the four-digit section
};  //and this wraps up the phone class
```

date.h

```
#ifndef date_h
#define date_h

#include <iostream> //this is the set of functions we need to "overload" and break out
using std::ostream; //use both output halves
using stf::istream; //and input halves

#include <string>
using std::string;


class Date
{
      friend ostream &operator<<( ostream &, const Date & ); //from example 11.3 in powerpoint 3
      friend ostream &operator>>( istream &, Date & ); //also from example 11.3 in powerpoint 3
private:
        string month;
        string day;
        string year;
};  //and this wraps up the date storage class

main.cpp

    #include <iomanip>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include "contact.h"
    #include "phone.h"
    #include "date.h"
    int main()
    {
//this is supposed to grab the numbers, and then i need something to grab the text and split it up
      char line_one[] = "Alex Liu 5592780000 06182011 15";
      char * pEnd;
      long int phone_number, date, minutes;
      phone_number = strtol (line_one,&pEnd,10);
      date = strtol (pEnd,&pEnd,10);
      minutes = strtol (pEnd,NULL,10);
      printf ("The numbers we get are: %ld, %ld, %ld.\n", phone_number, date, minutes);
      return 0;
    }
```

Is strtol the wrong function to use here?

Yes, this is part of a homework assignment.  Please don't assume I'm looking for a free handout, I really want t learn this.  Thanks, guys (and girls too!)

Comment: Do you have any code for us to work with? If you don't give us anything, then it is a free handout.

Answer (score 2):

So basically you want to read two strings and three integers. The basic way to do this in C++ is using streams:

```
std::string first_name, last_name;
std::int64_t number;
std::int32_t date, duration;

input_stream
    >> first_name >> last_name
    >> number >> date >> duration;
```

Where `input_stream` can either be an `std::istringstream` initialized from the string which you got as input, or an `std::ifstream` to read the contents of a file.

Comment: Are you sure `5593711872` will fit into an integer ?

Comment: @cnicutar: Good catch, I will fix it.

Comment: +1, though it'd be nice if you mentioned malformed input handling/detection

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to parse is using [streams](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/stringstream/):

```
std::ifstream fin("my_file.txt");
std::string name1, name2;
int number1, number2, number3;
fin >> name1 >> name2 >> number1 >> number2 >> number3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Whether you parse strings or files, you can always try using the corresponding stream classes, if you are sure you don't get malformed input.